Compare generic tuple in Swift
Playing around with Tuples and generics in Swift and wanting to understand if some experiments which I'm testing are achievable.
I created:
    struct TupleAssertion<T> {
        let value: T
    
        func assertValue<each Value: Equatable>(
            _ expectedValue: (repeat each Value)
        ) where (repeat each Value) == T {
            if value == expectedValue {
                print("Equal")
            } else {
                print("Not equaL")
            }
        }
    }

    let tupleAssertion = TupleAssertion(value: (1, 2))
    tupleAssertion.assertValue((1, 2))

But unfortunately I'm getting the error:

binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two '(repeat each Value)' operands

However this approach works:
    func createTuple<each Value: Equatable>(val: repeat each Value) -> (repeat each Value) {
        return (repeat each val)
    }
    
    createTuple(val: 1, 2) == (1, 2)
    createTuple(val: 1, 3) == (1, 2)

What changes are needed to get my first approach working?

Check this article https://www.swift.org/blog/pack-iteration/ maybe it will help

It looks like you've added parentheses to "work around" the fact that same-element requirements (== T) are not yet supported. Adding parentheses does not make something that isn't supported be supported. If you write it this way, you'll get the correct diagnostic:
) where repeat each Value == T {  // Same-element requirements are not yet supported

The way you've written it tries to make the type repeat each Value itself be equal to T, which is not what you mean.
Eventually this should be supported. It's part of the SE and it is intended to work. But it is not implemented yet.

I don't think OP intended to do same-element requirements.

You cannot use == on tuples of an arbitrary arity because tuples are not Equatable. There are only comparison operators defined for tuples of up to 6 elements (SE-015).
You can iterate over the value pack (SE-0408) and compare each element yourself though. You can do this in Swift 6:
func assertValue<each Value: Equatable>(
    _ expectedValue: (repeat each Value)
) where (repeat each Value) == T {
    for (actual, expected) in repeat (each value, each expectedValue) {
        if actual != expected {
            print("Not Equal")
            return
        }
    }
    print("Equal")
}

Since the struct is called TupleAssertions, it might make more sense to move the parameter pack to the struct:
struct TupleAssertion<each T: Equatable> {
    let value: (repeat each T)

    func assertValue( _ expectedValue: (repeat each T)) {
        // same code as before...
    }
}

Prior to Swift 6, it's a bit more convoluted to do this. (Adapted from the code in SE-0408)
struct TupleAssertion<each T: Equatable> {
    let value: (repeat each T)

    private struct NotEqual: Error {}

    func assertValue( _ expectedValue: (repeat each T)) {
        func isEqual<U: Equatable>(_ left: U, _ right: U) throws {
          if left == right {
            return
          }
          
          throw NotEqual()
        }

        do {
          repeat try isEqual(each value, each expectedValue)
        } catch {
            print("Not Equal!")
            return
        }

        print("Equal")
    }
}

Eventually, when SE-0283 is implemented, tuples of Equatable elements will conform to Equatable, and your current code will work without any changes.
